# JavaScript Event isn't waiting for user input

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo UI grid for a web app. I don't think that is important though for this question. The grid allows the contents to be exported to PDF. Before the export to PDF occurs you can set an event to fire first. I have done so and the JavaScript event function that fires looks as follows:

```
function onPdfExport(e) {
    alertify.prompt('Jeffreys', 'Enter text for the header (title) of the PDF document', '',
        function (evt, value) {
            pdfHeader = value;

            return true;
        },
        function () {
            return false;
        });
}
```

The problem is that while this function does indeed get called, the grid's export to PDF isn't waiting for the user to enter something in the prompt. I don't believe this is a Kendo grid issue. I think it's a lack of understanding on my part on to structure this function so that the export to PDF waits until the user enters something.

Comment: Can you add the standard prompt event?

Comment: @Nitheesh - Yes I could, and it works as I would expect. It just doesn't look very professional.

Comment: Just need to look into the method. Can you post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alertify.prompt()` function seems to be not blocking because you have to provide callbacks. It's unlike the native `prompt()`.

try: `pdfHeader = prompt('Enter text for the header (title) of the PDF document');`

The long answer is you need to restructure your code, so you can call the grid's export from the callback of your prompt.

Comment: The standard prompt() function does work as expected. I don't want to use it because it doesn't look very good.

Comment: @RandyMinder well can't you do the prompt before calling the PDFexport? Like `alertify.prompt('...',()=>{pdfHeader = value; --PDF.export();--}`

Answer (score 1):

I've read into the Kendo UI Api and found the e-promise chain, try this:

```
function onPdfExport(e) {
    alertify.prompt('Jeffreys', 'Enter text for the header (title) of the PDF document', '',
        function (evt, value) {
            pdfHeader = value;

            e.promise
               .done(function() {
                   alert("Export completed!");
               });
        },
        function () {
            return false;
        }
    );
}
```